# Spark Structured Streaming test late data

Tags: testing, spark-structured-streaming

Hi i was wondering if it is possible to manipulate processing time in unit-tests to allow testing for late data in Spark Structured Streaming.

I am inserting data as sequence into a `MemoryStream` in form of: `case class LineWithTimestamp(line: String, timestamp: Timestamp)`.
When inserting `LineWithTimestamp("a b b a", from(now.plus(ofSeconds(4))))` i want this event to be a few seconds later, so i can test allowed lateness/watermarks.

Thanks in advance.